# Vb.Net compiling error

Tags: vb.net

When I try and run my program in debug i keep receiving an error BC30456 it reads as follows:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   BC30456 'Form1' is not a member of 'serialtest2'.   serialtest2 C:\Users\Rhans\Desktop\VB6 Programs\Ethernet Socket\serialtest2\My Project\Application.Designer.vb  35  Active

I am looking to monitor a serial port that has a mettler toledo scale hooked to it and I am trying to display a continuous weight on the form...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The code is as follows:

```
 Imports System.IO.Ports
Imports System.IO.Ports.SerialPort


Public Class SerialCommunication

    Private WithEvents Port As New SerialPort


    Private Sub SerialCommunication_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        With Port
            .PortName = "COM5"
            .RtsEnable = True
            .BaudRate = 9600
            .Open()
        End With
    End Sub

    Private Sub port_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles Port.DataReceived
        Dim buffer As String = Port.ReadExisting()
        txtDisplay.Text = buffer
    End Sub
```

Comment: Somewhere in your code you have a reference to a non-existent Form1.  You created a VB.Net program in a "VB6 Programs" folder?  Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: Looks like there's a bunch of code missing.  Where's serialtest2?  Where's Form1?  What line is line 35?

Answer (score 0):

Your SerialCommunication Class replaces Form1 by the looks of it.

Go to Project > Properties then select Startup Form: Serial Communication or change the name of your class to "Form1" instead of "SerialCommunication"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and my solution came from Web.config. I had removed the default language from compilation node. When i put it back it worked fine.

```
<compilation debug="true" defaultLanguage="vb" targetFramework="4.5.2">
```